# Passing parameter to upload_to function in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I try to upload multiple images of an instance to different sub folders. But I need to rename each uploaded file as well so I implement a function for upload_to field as below.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField()
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path)
    cover = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path)

def get_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    new_name = "%s.%s" % (slughifi(filename), ext)
    return new_name
```

However, I'm not sure how I can divide images to subfolders like `logos` and `cover_images`
It'd better if I pass a parameter to get_path function like

```
    ...
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path("logos/"))
    cover = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path("cover_images/"))
    ...
```

Do I need to write different upload_to functions for each file field?

Answer (score 0):

i think no,

yo can use it like this:

```
upload_to=lambda s,f: MyModel.upload_to(s,f,your_custom_path)


@classmethod
def upload_to(cls, obj, filename, custom_path):
    name,extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    new_name = "%s.%s" % (slughifi(filename), extension)
    return "{}{}".format(custom_path, new_name)
```